# Set the the height of all items on a row of a GridView depending on the tallest item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-gridview

In an app that I'm developing I need to display a GridView with items that depending on its text (more than one line of text) may be of different height and I want to avoid that the items are shown with different heights since it's quite ugly.

When the text is only one line the GridView the items in the row are displayed properly but when the text is larger than one line they are shown like this:

[image]

How I can avoid this behavior and set the highest height of an item of a row as the height of all items of that row?

Comment: try height = match_parent?

Comment: @JoshuaByer Do you mean fill parent in each item? If so, it is not working.

Comment: Try to use TableLayout , you can set TableRow height WRAP_CONTENT, or set fixed item height, but i think it is not good.

Comment: @Natali TableLayout is not an option but thanks